# MongoDB - change simple field into an object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

In MongoDB, I want to change the structure of my documents from:

```
{
    discount: 10,
    discountType: "AMOUNT"
}
```

to:

```
{
    discount: {
        value: 10,
        type: "AMOUNT"
    }
}
```

so I tried following query in mongo shell:

```
db.discounts.update({},
    {
        $rename: {
             discount: "discount.value",
             discountType: "discount.type"
        }
    },
    {multi: true}
)
```

but it throws an error:

```
"writeError" : {
    "code" : 2,
    "errmsg" : "The source and target field for $rename must not be on the same path: discount: \"discount.value\""
}
```

A workaround that comes to my mind is to do it in 2 steps: first assign the new structure to a new field (let's say `discount2`) and then rename it to `discount`. But maybe there is a way to do it one step?

Comment: I can only think about the workaround you already proposed. I don't think there's a way to do it in one step

Comment: @SarathNair you may be right but there is better way to do this.

Comment: Are those fields the only field in your document a part from `_id`?

Comment: @user3100115 I am all ears :)

Comment: @user3100115 There are more fields but I excluded them for simplicity. They should stay untouched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to do it in two steps as you allude to in your question; initially renaming `discount` to a temporary field name so that it can be reused in the second step:

```js
db.discounts.update({}, {$rename: {discount: 'temp'}}, {multi: true})
db.discounts.update({}, 
    {$rename: {temp: 'discount.value', discountType: 'discount.type'}},
    {multi: true})
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this error is because as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/rename/#behavior):

> The `$rename` operator logically performs an `$unset` of both the old name and the new name, and then performs a `$set` operation with the new name. As such, the operation may not preserve the order of the fields in the document; i.e. the renamed field may move within the document.

And the problem with this is that you can't [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set) and [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/unset/#up._S_unset) same field at the same time in `MongoDB`.

The solution will be to use bulk operations to update your documents in order to change their structure, and even in that case you need to use a field's name that doesn't exist in your collection. Of course the best way to do all this is using ["Bulk"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk) operations for maximum efficiency

## MongoDB 3.2 or newer

MongoDB 3.2 deprecates [Bulk()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk) and its associated [methods.](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/js-bulk/) You need to use the [`.bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite) method.

```js
var operations = [];
db.discounts.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    var discount = doc.discount; 
    var discountType = doc.discountType; 
    var operation = { 'updateOne': { 
        'filter': { '_id': doc._id }, 
        'update': { 
            '$unset': { 'discount': '', 'discountType': '' }, 
            '$set': { 'discounts.value': discount, 'discounts.type': discountType }
        }
    }};
    operations.push(operation); 
});

operations.push( {
    ordered: true,      
    writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 5000 } 
});

db.discounts.bulkWrite(operations);
```

Which yields:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56682a02e6a2321d88f6d078"),
        "discounts" : {
                "value" : 10,
                "type" : "AMOUNT"
        }
}
```

---

## MongoDB 2.6

Prior to MongoDB 3.2 and using MongoDB version 2.6 or newer you can use the "Bulk" API.

```js
var  bulk = db.discounts.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;
db.discounts.find().forEach(function(doc) { 
    var discount = doc.discount; 
    var discountType = doc.discountType; 
    bulk.find( { '_id': doc._id } ).updateOne( {
        '$unset': { 'discount': '', 'discountType': '' }, 
        '$set': { 'discounts.value': discount, 'discounts.type': discountType }  }); 
   count++; 
   if (count % 500 === 0) {
       bulk.execute();
       bulk = db.discounts.initializeOrderedBulkOp(); 
    } 
})

if (count > 0)   
    bulk.execute();
```

This query yields same result as previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to answers from [Update MongoDB field using value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field) I figured out following solution:

```
db.discounts.find().snapshot().forEach(
    function(elem) {
        elem.discount = {
            value: elem.discount,
            type: elem.discountType
        }
        delete elem.discountType;
        db.discounts.save(elem);
    }
)
```

Which I quite like because the source code reads nicely but performance sucks for large amount of documents.

Comment: The problem with `save` is that it can also perform an insert unless you know what you are doing

Comment: Ah, I see. It shouldn't happen in my case but thanks for pointing it out. Now I know what I'm doing :)

Comment: and as you said this will cause drop of performance because you are doing it client side.